# Android state list for compound drawable

Tags: android, list, user-interface, drawable, state

Is it possible to define state list for compound drawables in Android?

This is my button in layout xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/btn_top"
    android:text="@string/button_text" />
```

This is my drawable xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_top_enabled" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_top_disabled" />
</selector>
```

This works for background, but its not working for drawableTop. The first state is always displayed. Is this even possible in Android, and if so am I missing something?

Comment: how did you fix it? i am facing same issue.

Comment: how did you solved the issue ? Drawable is not changing in text view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look ad TextView.java source code and you will see that yes, you can use StateListDrawable as a compound Drawable that displays according to TextView state

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_top_enabled" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_top_enabled" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_top_disabled" />
</selector>
```

And

```
button.setActivated(true);
```